# How to edit the content of a newly created App

Tags: facebook, editing

I have created a Facebook App that will be a page tab in an existing group. This app is live (visible to all users).

What I would like to know is, how can I edit the content of the actual app? At the moment when I click the "Web Preview" link, I get a page with the App layout and the screenshots as the contents, but I can't see anywhere to edit the actual content.

Comment: What "content" are you talking of?

Answer (score 0):

To edit your Facebook app, you need to go to
https://developers.facebook.com/apps and sign in, and then from there you click your app in the left hand corner and then on the right should be a button that says 'Edit App' and has a pencil icon. Click that and there you go, you can edit your Facebook app from there.